# Loop display only 5 posts

Tags: customization, loop

I`ve more than 5 posts with type job, but my script show only 5, and I know what is wrong.

```
get_header ();
$args = array (
        'post_type' => 'job'
);
$myposts = get_posts ( $args );

if (! defined ( 'WP_ADMIN_DIR' ))
    define ( 'WP_ADMIN_DIR', './wp-admin/' );


?>



<div class="main-content-bg"></div>

<div class="main-content marg">
    <div style="z-index: 1;">
        <div
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #fff; z-index: 2;">

            <div class="top-show">
                <?php 

                $top_success = false;

                while ($top_success == false) {

                $random_item = rand (0 , count($myposts) - 1); 

                $dwwp_stored_meta = get_post_meta ( $myposts[$random_item]->ID );

                $date_from = str_replace ( ".", "-", $dwwp_stored_meta ['date_from'] [0] );
                $date_to = str_replace ( ".", "-", $dwwp_stored_meta ['date_to'] [0] );

                $now = time ();

                $date_from = strtotime ( $date_from );
                $date_to = strtotime ( $date_to );

                $datediff_from = $now - $date_from;
                $datediff_to = $now - $date_to;
                $datediff_from = floor ( $datediff_from / (60 * 60 * 24) );
                $datediff_to = floor ( $datediff_to / (60 * 60 * 24) );
                if ($datediff_from >= 0 and $datediff_to <= 0) {
                    ?>  <img class="random_offer" id="<?php echo $myposts[$random_item]->ID; ?>" style="width:100%;" src="<?php echo WP_ADMIN_DIR . '/kupony/' . $myposts[$random_item]->ID  . '.png' ?>"/>

                <?php $top_success = true; 
                }
                } ?>


            </div>

            <div class="top-strip"><img src="http://staudtuili.cal24.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/top-strip.jpg" style="width:100%; visibility:hidden;"/></div>


<?php

try {
    $search = sanitize_text_field($_GET["search_box"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $search = "";
}



global $post;
global $all_post_titles; // ?possibly needed//
$all_post_titles = array ();

$count = 0;


foreach ( $myposts as $post ) :


    setup_postdata ( $post );
    $dwwp_stored_meta = get_post_meta ( $post->ID );
    $dwwp_stored_meta2 = get_post_meta ($dwwp_stored_meta['shop_id'][0]);
    $ajdi = $post->ID;

    $date_from = str_replace ( ".", "-", $dwwp_stored_meta ['date_from'] [0] );
    $date_to = str_replace ( ".", "-", $dwwp_stored_meta ['date_to'] [0] );

    $now = time (); 

    $date_from = strtotime ( $date_from );
    $date_to = strtotime ( $date_to );

    $datediff_from = $now - $date_from;
    $datediff_to = $now - $date_to;
    $datediff_from = floor ( $datediff_from / (60 * 60 * 24) );
    $datediff_to = floor ( $datediff_to / (60 * 60 * 24) );
        if ($datediff_from >= 0 and $datediff_to <= 0) {
        if (stripos($dwwp_stored_meta['name_id'][0], $search) !== false or !$search<>""){

        if ($count==0){
        ?>

        <div class="items-table">
                <div class="items-row">

        <?php  }?>
                    <div class="single-offer-uili" id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                    <a href="/kupon/?el_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration:none;">
                        <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <div id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" style="position:relative; width: 98%; background-size:auto, cover; display: inline-block; margin-top:3px; background-image: url('http://staudtuili.cal24.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/rabat_ol.png'), url('<?php $text =  $dwwp_stored_meta['image_url'][0]; echo $text;?>'); background-position: right bottom, center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                            <img 
                                id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" src="http://staudtuili.cal24.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/dummy_it.jpg"
                                style="visibility: hidden; width: 100%;" />
                            <div
                                id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" style="right: 5px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; color: #fff; font-size: 35px;"><?php $text =  $dwwp_stored_meta['rabat_id'][0]; echo $text;?></div>
                        </div>

</div>
                        <div
                            id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" style="height: 44px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align:left;">

                            <div id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" style="margin-left: 13px; margin-right: 13px">
         <?php $text =  $dwwp_stored_meta['name_id'][0]; echo $text;?> - <?php $text =  $dwwp_stored_meta2['name_id'][0]; echo $text;?>
       </div>



                        </div>
</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <img src="http://staudtuili.cal24.pl/wp-admin/kupony/?php echo $post->ID; ?>.png"></img> -->

<?php   if ($count==2){
        ?>  

                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
        $count = $count+ 1;
        if($count >= 3){
            $count = 0;
        }
    }}
endforeach;
```

if ($count != 0){
    for($x = $count; $x <3; $x++) {?>

```
<div class="single-offer-uili" id="00">
<div id="00" style="position:relative; width: 98%; background-color: #252525; background-size:auto, contain; display: inline-block; margin-top:3px; background-image: url(''), url('http://staudtuili.cal24.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/dummy_rt.png'); background-position: right bottom, center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <img id="00"
        src="http://staudtuili.cal24.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/dummy_it.jpg"
        style="visibility: hidden; width: 100%;" />
        <div id="00"
        style="right: 5px; bottom: 10px; position: absolute; color: #fff; font-size: 35px;"></div>
                        </div>


                        <div id="00"
                            style="height: 44px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">

                            <div id="00" style="margin-left: 13px; margin-right: 13px">Miejsce na Twoją zniżkę!</div>



                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `posts_per_page` option in query with value -1.

Check in back end settings->reading, number of posts to display in loop, if not using `posts_per_page`.